# What are polyhedrons?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, polyhedra

Polyhedrons or three dimensional analogues of polygons were studied by Euler who observed that if one lets $f$ to be the number of faces of a polyhedron, $n$ to be the number of solid angles and $e$ to be the number of joints where two faces come together side by side $n-e+f=2$.

It was later seen that a serious defect in this definition (and in the proof supplied by Euler) is that it is not at all clear what is a polyhedron in the first place. For example if we consider a cube nested within another cube as a polyhedron then $n-e+f=4$, a counter example to Euler's result.

What will be the modern definition of that polyhedron which will comply with Euler's result?

Comment: Are you asking specifically what class of two dimensional 'objects' the Euler characteristic is 2 for? (and I guess which captures the 'spirit' of Euler's original definition). If so, I guess a good candidate would be a 2-dimensional regular CW complex homeomorphic to a 2-sphere, and where $n$, $e$ and $f$ are respectively the $0$th, $1$st and $2$nd Betti numbers respectively.

Comment: Actually I guess you'd want $n$, $e$ and $f$ to be the rank of the corresponding cellular chain groups, rather than the Betti numbers, as these correspond to counting cells in the respective dimensions.

Comment: @DanRust I am asking for an appropriate definition of three dimensional solid satisfying $n-e+f=2$ and that solid should not shock our intuition of a polyhedron. Preferably an answer containing details explaining non-elementary terms used in the definition.

Comment: The question is discussed at great length in the book by Imre Lakatos, Proofs and Refutations. It will give you a lengthy, rather than a quick, answer to your question, but it's a terrific read.

Comment: McMullen and Schulte also discuss this a bit, I believe, in their book *Abstract Regular Polytopes*. The idea is that it's much easier to describe posets that "behave like" the face lattices of ordinary polyhedra, than to decide how all the non-conventional polyhedra can be axiomatized. It won't give you an answer, but it stems from a related inquiry.

Comment: See [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polyhedra that Euler studied was not the same as we call polyhedra today. Today a polyhedra is a body with (only) flat polygonal faces.

Those that Euler studied was a subset of these. Basically those whose nodes and vertices form a planar graph.

There are some complications that can arise in the generic definition that Euler did not consider.

The most striking is that it that it allows for cutting out the inside of it, that is that it's surface would not need to be connected.

Another is that you may have donut-like polyhedra, ie take a polyhedron and make a prism shaped hole through it.

A third is the assumption that the edges and vertices might not form a connected graph. For example if you glue together two differently sized cubes at one face (so that the smaller sits on the face of the other).

The second construct will decrease the euler characteristics and the third will increase it. The consequence is that you could combine these complications to result in a polyhedron that Euler didn't consider, but that nevertheless satisfies his formula.

Comment: I think there are polyhedra homotopic to a ball that don't satisfy the Euler relation, in particular, if they have faces that are not simply connected.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think that would help. The image of the polyhedron would be a ball with subsurfaces, curves and nodes just the same number as the polyhedron.

Comment: take a cube, and put a little cube on top of it, so what used to be the top of the cube is now (topologically) an annulus. I count 16 vertices, 24 edges, 11 faces.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes you're correct.

Comment: So is it incorrect to say a solid with flag polygonal faces and homotopic to a ball is an Eulerian polyhedron?

Comment: @Shahab Yes, I've updated the answer and included Gerry's counter example as well.

Comment: I have two questions: Firstly do you mean to say that Eulerian polyhedrons are those which when projected to the plane yield planar graphs? Secondly where can I find a proof that this condition is sufficient, i.e. there do not exist any other polyhedron for which $n-e+f=2$ besides those which yield planar graphs?

Comment: @Shehab [Steinitz' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz's_theorem) is something similar, I'm not sure if this is what is being alluded to (it's definitely somewhat different).

Comment: @Shahab The proof is available on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Proof_of_Euler.27s_formula however these are not the only polyhedra that have euler characteristic of one. You can put holes through it to decrease it and use the construct where the edges isn't connected - for example put a prismshaped hole through a cube.

Comment: @skyking: "however these are not the only polyhedra that have euler characteristic of one." Don't you mean euler characteristic of two?

Comment: Yes, it should be two.

Answer (score 2):

It simplifies matters to insist that all faces ("components" below)
be convex polygons, and permitting coplanar faces (partitioning
any nonconvex face into convex pieces). Then

---

[image: CGinC101]

---

I have a discussion expanding these three conditions on pp.101-104 of
[*Computational Geometry in C*](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html), which is available via Google Books.